# PHP won't load data on first page load at JavaScript HTTP request

Tags: javascript, php, session

I'm sending data with a JavaScript HTTP request to PHP, I want the PHP to keep it in it's memory. Therefor, i'm using `$_SESSIONS`'s. I'm doing this because i dont want to do any calculation or HTML deployment with JavaScript.

Here's my method how i'm sending data to PHP:

```
/**
 * The PHP file which receives the data
 *
 * @type {string} The php filename
 */
const INSTALL_FILE = "install.php";

/**
 * Passes roadTaxData to the php install file which could be getData with the $_POST operator
 */
function passToPHP (paramName, data) {
    var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity"
    httpc.open("POST", INSTALL_FILE, true); // sending as POST
    httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpc.send(paramName + "=" + data);
}
```

I'm using the method like this:

```
/**
 * @type {string} The data which is getting send to PHP
 */
var data = "";

/**
 * Parses the road tax data and stores it into the data string as JSON format
 */
function parseRoadTaxData () {
    var object = {};
    /*
     Loop through all the road tax data
     */
    for (var vehicleFormatType in roadTaxData) {
        /*
         Define all vehicle types which belong to that vehicle type format
         */
        var vehicleTypes = roadTaxData[vehicleFormatType];

        /*
         Loop through all the vehicle types
         */
        for (var vehicleType in vehicleTypes) {
            /*
             Add the vehicle data to the JSON object
             */
            object[vehicleType.toLowerCase()] = vehicleTypes[vehicleType];
        }
    }
    /*
     Parse the javascript object (converted to JSON format) into the data string.
     */
    data = JSON.stringify(object);
}

/**
 * Gets the data which is going to be send to PHP
 *
 * @returns {string} The JSON data string
 */
function getData () {
    return data;
}

/*
 Call the function to parse all data into the HTTP query string
 */
parseRoadTaxData();

/*
 Call the function to pass the whole HTTP query to PHP in seperate $_POST variables
 */
passToPHP('road-tax_data', getData());
```

The `install.php` file, which is receiving the data looks like this: It opens a session and stores the data in the `RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry` class.

```
require "RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry.php";

/*
 * Start the session
 */
session_start();


RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry::store(json_decode($_POST['road-tax_data'], true));
```

My `RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry` class looks like this:

```
/**
 * Storage for all road tax data
 */
class RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry
{
    /**
     * The character which gets and sets the specific $_SESSION
     */
    const SESSION_NAME = 'rtd';

    /**
     * Stores all data in a session
     *
     * @param $data array The data which is getting stored
     */
    public static function store ($data) {
        $_SESSION[self::SESSION_NAME] = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the road tax data of a vehicle
     *
     * @param string $vehicle
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getStorageByVehicle ($vehicle) {
        return $_SESSION[self::SESSION_NAME]["$vehicle"];
    }
}
```

This class does nothing more then just storing variables into a specific `$_SESSION` key.

My `index.php` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="data/js-files/data_personen_auto.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/road_tax_data_mapper.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/utility.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/data_parser.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php  
    require "RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry.php";

    session_start();

    var_dump(RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry::getStorageByVehicle($myCar));

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I first import all the JavaScript scripts, which are sending the data to PHP.

Then in the body of my html page, i'm opening the session and calling up and printing out the data i've just parsed in that class via the HTTP request.

**Problem**

When I open this for the first time in my browser (open via my IDE PhpStorm) i get this error message:

Notice: Undefined index: rtd in C:\Users\Bas.\Cars\RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry.php on line 30
NULL

When I refresh the page, the data is getting printed out how it should:

```
array(1) { ["noord_holland"]=> array(46) { [0]=> string(14) "1#26#90#26#101" [1]=> string(17) "551#34#109#34#124" [2]=> string(17) "651#42#129#42#147" [3]=> string(17) "751#55#154#55#175" [4]=> string(17) "851#73#189#87#203" [5]=> string(18) "951#94#223#123#238" [6]=> string(20) "1051#115#257#159#273" [7]=> string(20) "1151#137#290#195#309" [8]=> string(20) "1251#158#324#230#344" [9]=> string(20) "1351#180#358#266#379" [10]=> string(20) "1451#201#392#302#414" [11]=> string(20) "1551#222#426#338#449" [12]=> string(20) "1651#244#460#374#485" [13]=> string(20) "1751#265#494#409#520" [14]=> string(20) "1851#286#528#445#555" [15]=> string(20) "1951#308#562#481#590" [16]=> string(20) "2051#329#596#517#625" [17]=> string(20) "2151#351#630#553#661" [18]=> string(20) "2251#372#664#588#696" [19]=> string(20) "2351#393#698#624#731" [20]=> string(20) "2451#415#732#660#766" [21]=> string(20) "2551#436#766#696#801" [22]=> string(20) "2651#458#800#732#837" [23]=> string(20) "2751#479#834#768#872" [24]=> string(20) "2851#500#868#803#907" [25]=> string(20) "2951#522#902#839#942" [26]=> string(20) "3051#543#936#875#977" [27]=> string(21) "3151#564#969#911#1013" [28]=> string(22) "3251#582#1000#943#1044" [29]=> string(22) "3351#600#1030#975#1075" [30]=> string(23) "3451#617#1060#1006#1106" [31]=> string(23) "3551#634#1089#1038#1138" [32]=> string(23) "3651#651#1119#1070#1169" [33]=> string(23) "3751#669#1149#1102#1200" [34]=> string(23) "3851#686#1179#1133#1231" [35]=> string(23) "3951#703#1209#1165#1262" [36]=> string(23) "4051#720#1239#1197#1293" [37]=> string(23) "4151#738#1269#1228#1324" [38]=> string(23) "4251#755#1298#1260#1355" [39]=> string(23) "4351#772#1328#1292#1386" [40]=> string(23) "4451#790#1358#1324#1418" [41]=> string(23) "4551#807#1388#1355#1449" [42]=> string(23) "4651#824#1418#1387#1480" [43]=> string(23) "4751#841#1448#1419#1511" [44]=> string(23) "4851#859#1477#1450#1542" [45]=> string(23) "4951#876#1507#1482#1573" } }
```

**Question**

How do I make the page automaticly load the data without having to refresh the page?

**My own try**

I've put this JavaScript code into my `passPHP()` function:

```
httpc.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
    if (httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { // complete and no errors
        window.location.href = "index.php";
    }
};
```

This automaticly refreshed the page, but this was to slow and you actually saw the page that said that the array index was'nt defined.

- Note: I dont want to use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I should use AJAX again to load the values once the former request returns.

The flow:

1. Use AJAX to post your data into a session using `parseRoadTaxData`
2. Attach an event handler to that AJAX call `onreadystatechange`
3. Wait for a `readystate` of `4` and make a new AJAX call now retrieving your session data through a PHP file running `RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry::getStorageByVehicle($myCar)`

extending your AJAX call with onreadystate

```
function setAndLoadData(INSTALL_FILE, paramName , data)
{
    var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity"
    httpc.open("POST", INSTALL_FILE, true); // sending as POST
    httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpc.onreadystatechange = retrieveVarsFromPHP //<-- call this on readystatechange.
    httpc.send(paramName + "=" + data);
}

function retrieveVarsFromPHP()
{
    if (this.readyState == 4)
    {
         //AJAX call to retrieve data.
         var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity"
         httpc.open("get", retrieveSessionData.php, true);
         httpc.onreadystatechange = function()
         {
             if (this.readyState == 4)
             {
                 sessionData = JSON.parse(this.responseText); //Store the data in a global, which can be accessed in the index.html
                 callBack() //this can be a function in your page called upon to handle displaying the retrieved data.
             }
         } 
         httpc.send();
    }

}
```

PHP file `retrieveSessionData.php`

```
<?php
require "RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry.php";

session_start();

echo (RoadTaxDataTemporaryRegistry::getStorageByVehicle($myCar));
?>
```

Execute on index.php

```
 <script>
      setAndLoadData();
 </script>
```

Your problem with retrieving the data lays in the `asynchronous` part of `AJAX`. The data isn't really set yet while `PHP` starts parsing the data. You need to wait for this to finish. The refreshing of the page was a hint in that direction, but you still can't rely on that. Because the fact that the page finishes loading says nothing about the fact that of your asynchronous AJAX call running besides the page-loading is finished.

I hope I made sense.

Comment: I dont really get what you mean, ajax is jquery only right?

Comment: no AJAX is the method you are using. `A`synchronous `J`avascript `A`nd `X`ML.  In JavaScript you use `xmlHttpRequest` for this. Only this evolved over time and you can also load text, JSON, or other contents besides XML through this type of request. AJAX can send and receive data asynchronous so it's not locking up your browser while executing.

Comment: Okay, but i dont get how i can solve this issue then

Comment: You want to retrieve data, but the data isn't set when you access it with PHP. My script waits for the data to be set and then retrieves the data.

Comment: But where do i call that then?

Comment: Where the comment `AJAX call to retrieve data` is in my answer.

Comment: oo like that, now i get it.. But i want to get that data inside my index.php, because all the data is getting handled there

Comment: Edited it again to reflect this

Comment: thanks but your newly updated answer doesnt make sense by its functions. In your 'setAndLoadData' method the paramName and value part is undefined.

Comment: @Bas Added the necessary arguments to the function. Should work now. This is the flow: first it post the data to the server. When done a callback is fired which retrieves the newly set data. When the data is returned to the page it's stored in the `global` `sessionData`  and a (custom) `callBack()` is called upon. You can rename this function. When this `callBack` is executed you can access your data by calling `sessionData`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67841/discussion-between-bas-and-mouser).